# How to create generic type reference with Roslyn?

Tags: roslyn

I want to create a reference to "`System.IEquatable<MyType>`", where the open generic type can be reached via `typeof` and the generic argument as text only. How do I create a correct `NameSyntax` that can be used as field type, etc.?

We recently used `SF.ParseName` which creates a `QualifiedNameSyntax` (not a `GenericNameSyntax` what wonders me). However, I think this is not ideal, since I'm dealing with `<`, `>` and string.Join on my own.

Comment: The last component of the `QualifiedNameSyntax` should be a `GenericNameSyntax`.

Comment: You can use http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ to see how to generate a piece of syntax using the apis. Just paste in "System.IEquatable<MyType>"

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's a perfect helper if you don't want to install VS2015 and the visualizer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
SF.GenericName(
    SF.Identifier(@"IEquatable"))
.WithTypeArgumentList(
    SF.TypeArgumentList(/.../))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in the workspace layer, you can also use the SyntaxGenerator type to do this in a language independent way:

```
var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(document);
generator.QualifiedName(generator.IdentifierName("System"),
                        generator.GenericName(generator.IdentifierName("IEquatable"), 
                                              new [] { generator.IdentifierName("MyType") }));
```

This will generate System.IEquatable< MyType> for C# and System.IEquatable(Of MyType) for VB documents.